# How to access Oracle Rdb from Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, jdbc, odbc, oracle-rdb

Part of our company's data is stored in Oracle Rdb database system running on OpenVMS. Processes running on our VMs connect to this database using ODBC driver.

We're now moving most of our backend to .NET microservices deployed on Kubernetes cluster and moving data to newer DB system. However, there's still a need to sometimes load data from Oracle Rdb.

Is there any way to access Oracle Rdb database from Linux-based and dockerized Kubernetes pods?